# Calling an array in constructor in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to call an array in the constructor and allocate it to variables like so:

```
private int x1;
private int y1; 
private int x2;
private int y2; 
private int x3;
private int y3;
private int x4;
private int y4; 

int[] array1 = new int[7];

public ChangePlane(String name, int[] array1){ 
this.name = name; 
this.array1 = array1;
array1[0]=x1;
array1[1]=y1;
array1[2]=x2;
array1[3]=y2;
array1[4]=x3;
array1[5]=y3;
array1[6]=x4;
array1[7]=y4;
}
```

I am using this constructor to be able to call a set of four coordinates to draw a square around an image. But the code is not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by not working ? I see lots of error/bug, which one you are concerned about

Comment: Well I am new to java, I just want to be able to call the constructor and create a name and a set of 8 values and store it in the constructor so I can use those stored values later.

Comment: There are so many ***correct*** answers, but I'm not 100% sure what is correct for OP...since the problem is a bit unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the assignments reversed,

```
public ChangePlane(String name, int[] array1){ 
  this.name = name; 
  this.array1 = array1;
  x1 = array1[0];
  y1 = array1[1];
  x2 = array1[2];
  y2 = array1[3];
  x3 = array1[4];
  y3 = array1[5];
  x4 = array1[6];
  y4 = array1[7];
}
```

Assuming you are passing an `int[] array1 = new int[8];` (since array1[7] will fail otherwise) to your constructor anyway.

Comment: That's all I needed, thank you Mr.Frisch.

Answer (score 1):

consider passing an object instead of the array. The object can contain the properties.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing this:

```
array1[0]=x1;
array1[1]=y1;
array1[2]=x2;
array1[3]=y2;
array1[4]=x3;
array1[5]=y3;
array1[6]=x4;
array1[7]=y4;
```

You're filling the array with zeros because x1, y1, etc... are not initialized.

This code:

```
int[] array1 = new int[7];
```

is useless because you're assigning to array1 the array that is passed as a parameter to the constructor. And BTW, when you're assigning x1, y1, etc... to array[0], array[1], etc... you're also altering the array that was passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a class variable named **name**. Where did you assigned this.name?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Square {
  private String name;
  private int[] points;

  public Square(String name, int[] points){ 
    this.name = name; 
    this.points= points;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int[] getPoints() {
    return points;
  }
}
```

Create a Square object with name and points

```
Square square = new Square("first", new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4})
```

you can use the object whenever you want to access the points

```
square.getPoints()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there area quite a few things you need to consider:

```
private int x1; // Why would you set those integers as private 
private int y1; // if they are just used to initiate your array's values 
private int x2;
private int y2; 
private int x3;
private int y3;
private int x4;
private int y4; 

int[] array1 = new int[7]; // your array might as well be private if you intent
// to use it through the whole class

public ChangePlane(String name, int[] array1){ 
this.name = name; // this.name isn't define in the class' private parameters, it doesn't exists
this.array1 = array1; // this array should be private
array1[0]=x1; // how are the x values inputed in your program?
array1[1]=y1;
array1[2]=x2;
array1[3]=y2;
array1[4]=x3;
array1[5]=y3;
array1[6]=x4;
array1[7]=y4;
}
```